# I am attempting to code a program where a user enters a set of numbers into a vector, and the program gives "stats" back

Tags: c++

I have to make a program where a user can entire an infinite amount of integers until they type
"-1", which would end the program and print back the total sum, average, min, and max values from what the user entered. So far I have gotten the sum and max values, but the average doesn't print to right number, and the min value only prints the -1.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<float> v;
    int n = 0;
    int sum1;
    float avg2, tsum;

    while (true) {
        cout << "Give me another number, or enter '-1' to stop:" << endl;
        cin >> n;

        v.push_back(n);

        float avg2 = accumulate(v.begin(), v.end()) / v.size();
        int sum1 = accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);
        int tsum = sum1 + 1;

        if (n == -1) {
            cout << "Total sum: " << tsum << endl;

            cout << "Average: " << avg2 << endl;

            cout << "\nMin Element: = " << *min_element(v.begin(), v.end()) << endl;
            cout << "\nMax Element: = " << *max_element(v.begin(), v.end()) << endl;

            cout << "All Done" << endl;

            break;

            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the problem stems from taking -1 into the vector and calculate the average etc before checking for it. You should prevent it from entering the vector

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<float> v;
    int n = 0;

    while (true) {
        cout << "Give me another number, or enter '-1' to stop:" << endl;
        cin >> n;

        if (n == -1) {
            int tsum = accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);
            float avg2 = tsum / v.size();
            

            cout << "Total sum: " << tsum << endl;

            cout << "Average: " << avg2 << endl;

            cout << "\nMin Element: = " << *min_element(v.begin(), v.end()) << endl;
            cout << "\nMax Element: = " << *max_element(v.begin(), v.end()) << endl;

            cout << "All Done" << endl;

            break;
        }

        v.push_back(n);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

> **Note** that you was calculating for each input; This is faster, as it only counts on `-1` input.

Comment: You can simplify the logic here with `while (cin >> n && n != -1)`